# How does the jquery data method works when a constructor function is pass as an argument value?

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me understand this code?

```
$(this).data("obj",new Storage());
```

One question, the data key of "obj" is it the instance of Storage constructor? And how can I access this object from the data method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the newly created instance that `new Storage()` creates is stored internally in jQuery's  data object.

To access it, you can do

```
$(this).data("obj");
```

For instance

```
var Storage = function() {}

Storage.prototype.stuff = function() {
    console.log('hello kitty');
}

$(this).data("obj",new Storage()); // create a new instance

$(this).data("obj").stuff(); // logs "hello kitty"
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jy9u6nr9/)

Answer (score 0):

> One question, the data key of "obj" is it the instance of Storage constructor?

Yes. It is the resulting object.

> And how can I access this object from the data method?

```
var obj = $(this).data("obj");
```